# WinForm C# events when calling DLL (opencv)

Tags: c#, winforms, opencv, ui-thread

I am developing a simple winform application which calls a C++ Opencv DLL.
Something regarding the UI-thread events happens which is strange to me. The WinForm should be frozen when the DLL is called inside an infinite while-loop (which in turn is inside a button event handler).
Anyway if the called opencv function does not contain the  `cv:pollKey();` everything is frozen. If the pollKey or waitKey is present the winForm app is responsive!

If responsive I can change the value of 'key' so that the loop can stop.

The DLL functions are loaded in C# in this way (example):

```
[DllImport(@"Track3D_DLL_opencv45.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] 
public static unsafe extern int GetFrame();
```

The Button handler contains this code:

```
key = -1;
while (key < 0)
{
    nFrame++;

    int res1 = m_Model.GetFrame_();
    int res2 = m_Model.Processing_(false);
    Invoke(new Action(() => { MSG.Text = "frame " + nFrame.ToString() + "     key " + key.ToString(); }));
    Console.WriteLine("frame " + nFrame.ToString() + " key " + key.ToString());
}
```

Note that if the GetFrame_  and Processing_ calls are commented out, the event handler correctly makes the application frozen.
If I leave the DLL doing its basic job, getting a frame and processing it (just canny for example) and showing it, then the WinForm as I said become responsive!
It seems that the second of these two lines is resposible of this behaviour.

```
imshow("image", view);
key = pollKey(); // if commented everything get frozen
```

What is happening to the UI threads here? How an instruction which is part of an unmanaged code could unfreeze the main UI-thread of a WinForm app?

Furthermore, when the winForm is responsive I could click again that button an another infinite while loop is executed during the first.
Does this mean that every winForm event launches a separate thread?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the [emgu open CV wrapper](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It might not affect this specific problem, but I would expect it to be easier to use in general.

Comment: *do not* run long processing tasks inside of event handlers! they run in the main loop, which does the event processing. use a worker thread instead. *something* has to process events to the GUI. OpenCV's waitKey can do that... but it might not do that properly for your specific program!

Comment: @ Christoph,  thank you. I will definetly use a worker thread. But is interesting that waitKey  which is in charge of processing the opencv unmaneged GUIs  affects  the events of winForms. I thought the enviroments and message-queues were totally separated.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz. worker threads do not work,  the same for BackgroundWorker.  The imshow("image",view) blocks the execution (without errors).  It seems that only in the C# UI thread (the button handle) the imshow and pollkey opecv functions of the DLL work.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not actionable. you don't even show what you tried and what exactly happened. I can't help with C# anyway.